# Need an alternative to the Canon 5D Mark IV

Tags: canon, dslr

As a film student that is graduating soon, the 5D Mark IV seems like the perfect DSLR to get my photography/cinematography business started. I primarily plan on doing lifestyle, business and event work and need a diverse camera that can do all of the above well on both the photography and cinematography side.

The lens I'm looking to pair with the camera is the Canon 24-70mm f/2.8L, which I consider to be a nice diverse focal range for what I'm doing.

I've been doing research for months now. I've looked at the Canon 7D Mark II, the Canon 5D Mark III and plenty of other mid-ranged DSLR's. For some reason I always find my way back to the 5D Mark IV.

I'm looking to find the right DSLR to get the job done, but for a good value. Your input would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Please read [Q&A is Hard, Let's Go Shopping](https://stackoverflow.blog/2010/11/23/qa-is-hard-lets-go-shopping/) to understand why this sort of question generally isn't a good fit for Stack Exchange.

Comment: If the 5DMkIV is perfect, why do you need an alternative?

Comment: The 5D Mark IV is a great, but spending $3,300 on the body alone is something I'm only going to do if its necessary. I'm just wondering if there is another option that can get the job done for less, while keeping the same standard for quality.

Comment: 5D Mk III, 6D (Mk II),... - what's wrong with them?

Comment: I don't really see a question here. Need to be more explicit about the problem. Reading between the lines, I think you are unsure whether the Canon 7D Mark II or Canon 5D Mark III can "get the job done". What exactly are you unsure about with respect to those models? Also, "a good value" is entirely subjective. Nobody can help you with that consideration.

Comment: Just graduated and you're already exhibiting symptoms of GAS. Kevin, I highly recommend you see someone about this.

Comment: If you don't want to send it in for realignment every time it gets bumped a bit, you should probably consider the EF 24-70mm f/2.8 L II rather than the EF 24-70mm f/2.8 L. The Tamron SP 24-70mm f/2.8 Di VC is better than the old Canon and includes optical stabilization. If you don't need f/2.8 the EF 24-70mm f/4 L IS is a more budget minded option that includes 0.7X MM for Macro usage. (Some folks consider anything with a 0.5X MM/1:2 reproduction ratio a macro lens, others insist that only 1.0X/1:1 are "true" macro lenses. The EF 24-70mm f/4 L falls directly between those two standards.)

Answer (score 6):

> As a film student that is graduating soon, the 5D Mark IV seems like the perfect DSLR to get my photography/cinematography business started.

**You don't need to buy a 5D Mark IV.** What you need is a business plan that clearly lays out what you have and how you're going to use it to start making money. Who are your customers? How much can you reasonably charge? Whatever you charge, it should more than cover your costs, including equipment, your time, materials, etc. Use whatever equipment you do have, and rent what you need but don't have. If you can make money working this way, then you'll reach a point where it makes more sense to buy the equipment you use most often than it does to rent it, because a) you have enough money saved to buy, and b) owning will reduce your costs and therefore increase your profit.

Comment: +1 - and I want to put even more emphasis on **rent before you buy**. You (op) *think* you need a 5Dmk4 - but it sounds like you've never used it. Rent to test it out on your own projects, and rent again for your first few gigs. Only once you've honed in on your exact requirements should you buy.